# How can I do an inbuilt compile of rtl8723be firmware into a custom linux kernel?

Tags: wireless, kernel, bluetooth, realtek, firmware

### Issue

The kernel I built/compiled, has erros loading the firmware for both the bluetooth and wifi as **all** modules are inbuilt

I ran

```
bret@asus:~$ sudo dmesg
```

### Wifi Error

```
[    2.428254] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin
[    2.428546] rtl8723be 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin failed with error -2
[    2.428596] rtl8723be 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin failed with error -2
[    2.428599] rtlwifi: Loading alternative firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin
[    2.428601] rtlwifi: Selected firmware is not available
```

### Bluetooth Error

```
[    3.273984] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[    3.273991] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[    3.274046] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[    3.274049] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[    3.274076] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    3.274078] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
```

I dont wish to compile loadable modules since it would not befit the purpose, like the solution given [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Realtek-8723DE-wifi-module-amp-Bluetooth-Linux-driver/td-p/6477307/page/4)

Hence how can I compile the firmware files for the wifi into the kernel itself or better yet make the kernel recognise them in

```
/lib/firmware/rtlwifi
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in that module. I suspect the developers intended it to work properly without recompiling at home. Is this a stock Ubuntu kernel, or did you add this module from someplace?

Comment: I doubt the user is using Ubuntu as the linux-firmware package should be installed

Comment: I complied the kernel myself. The stock one works just fine. I wanted to make a custom kernel with all necessary mudules. Its the one which is failing to load the wifi driver's firmware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Generate a kernel configuration

After generating a config with

```
make localmodconfig
# then with a text editor find and replace =m with =y
gedit .config # find and replace =m with =y
```

or

```
make localyesconfig
```

Which I didn't try but i think it does the above a once. I haven't tried it.

### Editing the configuration

```
gedit .config
```

Find the line with `# Firmware loader`
My new config was edited to reflect

```
CONFIG_FW_LOADER=y
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE="rtlwifi/rtl8723befw_36.bin rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin"
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR="/lib/firmware"
```

After `make` and `make install`, the new kernel loads the firmware correctly and nicely now I am running with a bug-less compact kernel